# How to align button text to parent layout instead of button itself?

Tags: android, android-layout, listitem

This is the `recyclerview` item layout I want to create [image]

As you can see from the image, the **start of text(Action 01) in the button(green box) is aligned to the start of the parent layout(red box)**, not the start of the button.
I want to create a layout like this. If the button text is small, the button should move to the left so that the button text is aligned to the start of parent layout. Is it possible to create a layout like this in android?

Setting `gravity="start"` is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using negative margin but that will cut your view.